# What exactly does ssh-add do?

Tags: ssh

I recently reinstalled my laptop and found that 'git clone' wasn't working.  I was consistently receiving `Permission denied (publickey).` errors.

The fix is documented on GitHub's [SSH issues](http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/) page: use `ssh-add` to tell SSH about the key I want to use to authenticate on GitHub.

My question is: under the hood, what does `ssh-add` actually do?

I've been meaning to expand my understanding of SSH for a while, & this seems like a good excuse to start :-)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`ssh-add` adds private key identities (from your `~/.ssh` directory) to the authentication agent (`ssh-agent`), so that the ssh agent can take care of the authentication for you, and you don’t have type in passwords at the terminal.

Comment: I'll be honest, this confused me for a while.  I thought the ssh client always used the key in your `~/.ssh` directory.  Do some distros do the equivalent of `ssh-add` automatically?  Maybe that's why I was confused?

Comment: `ssh` does use the key in the `~/.ssh` directory, but if the key is protected by a passphrase, this passphrase must be entered at some point. If you use `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`, you type this passphrase once. Otherwise you must type the passphrase each time you use `ssh`. Note that if the key is not password protected, you can use `ssh` without being asked for a passphrase.

Comment: There can be multiple ssh keys in `~/.ssh` and this might be the more useful thing to have, see [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419609/444255) and [bitbucket docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/04/different-ssh-keys-multiple-bitbucket-accounts/)

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this article in github](https://help.github.com/articles/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign), sometime on some linux distributions even after you set up everything properly this error shows up:

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

And you should run `ssh-add` to solve the issue.

Comment: Worked for me! Would I have to run `ssh-add` everytime though? I restarted my MacOS and had to run this again.