# General Understanding of SSH-Add and SSH-Agent in Windows?

Tags: ssh

In relation to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/360686/what-exactly-does-ssh-add-do/1811104#1811104) question. I wrote a response as well but I'll repost here, as not sure if that post will be read because of the date of the original post.

Each time I start a terminal session I have to first use `ssh-add` first to add the key; key being the `id_rsa`. Although in Windows rather command how do I use SSH-Agent as it doesn't exist in Windows so that I'm not prompt for the password for that terminal session ?

Comment: Does the answer here (and the comments) answer your question? https://superuser.com/a/1354118/673426 . SSH Agent does exist in windows as a service named "OpenSSH Authentication Agent" (short name `ssh-agent`).

Comment: When trying to install OpenSSH as by this site; https://www.hawaii.edu/askus/1874#:~:text=You%20can%20enable%20the%20OpenSSH%20Client%20on%20your,Windows%20will%20then%20install%20the%20OpenSSH%20client.%20

It doesn't exist in my Windows11 ?

Comment: I believe it gets installed by default in current Win10/11 builds. Check if you have `ssh.exe` etc located in `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ `? Otherwise take a look through the MS doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=powershell

Comment: I have ssh.exe as well as all other ssh related files in the OpenSSH folder. 

Although when I'm directly in the path to OpenSSH and all related SSH files or I'm not in the direct path when I try to add `id_rsa.pub` to ssh-add I get; `Error Connecting to agent: No such file or directory` ?

Comment: Is the `ssh-agent` service running? Looks like it's disabled by default. Set the start type to Manual or Automatic, then start it, and it should work better